# CRM showing the wrong filtering criteria for a SQL report

Tags: sql, filter, report, dynamics-crm-2011, criteria

I have created a report using SQL query :

```
select 
CRMAF_FilteredPhoneCall.actualstart,
CRMAF_FilteredPhoneCall.createdon,
CRMAF_FilteredPhoneCall.new_activityid,
CRMAF_FilteredPhoneCall.new_activitydescription,
CRMAF_FilteredPhoneCall.new_clienttype,
CRMAF_FilteredPhoneCall.new_callrating,
CRMAF_FilteredPhoneCall.directioncode,
CRMAF_FilteredPhoneCall.ownerid,
FilteredActivityParty.partyid,
FilteredActivityParty.participationtypemask,
FilteredActivityParty.ActivityPartyid,
FilteredContact.Address1_StateOrProvince

from FilteredPhoneCall as CRMAF_FilteredPhoneCall
LEFT JOIN FilteredActivityParty on FilteredActivityParty.activityid=CRMAF_FilteredPhoneCall.activityid
LEFT JOIN FilteredContact on FilteredContact.ContactId=FilteredActivityParty.partyid
order by CRMAF_FilteredPhoneCall.actualstart desc
```

What I would expect is that this would give me only Phone Call in the Filtering criteria, however, it also displays "Appointment". I haven't even selected anything related to appointments in that query, why is the CRM including it in the filter ?

I tried to delete and upload the report, but it still showed the filter for appointments.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turned out that there is a parameter in the report itself "@CRM_FilteredAppointment" and it was causing this problem.